# Customize cppcheck ruleset

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I'm using Cppcheck for static code analysis. What I want to achieve is modify some rules in terms of "severity", for instance, I want to change severity of rule ***uninitMemberVar*** from **style** to **warning** (this is just an example).

Is there a way to achieve this?
Where can I find the complete cppcheck ruleset?

Answer (score 3):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

The uninitMemberVar is a warning already. I recommend that you use --xml-version=2.

For your info, the default --xml format is version 1. In this format there is only error and style. All non-error messages are shown as style. This format is default because of compatibility against old plugins/scripts/tools - but maybe we can consider to make version 2 default now as we have recommended version 2 for many years.

To get a list of all error messages, use --errorlist. For example:

```
cppcheck --errorlist --xml-version=2
```

Comment: I have a doubt, can I edit that error list and use it as custom ruleset? BTW change unitMemberVar from style to warning is just an example. I want to change severity of any rule I need

Comment: if that is not enough, then I recommend that you edit the report. For instance you could use xslt.

Comment: I run cppcheck --errorlist --xml-version=2 and saved the output in a file named my-rules.xml, then I try to run cppcheck --rule-file=my-rules.xml file.c, but I got the error cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--rule-file=my-rules.xml"

Comment: I realized rule-file option starts in version 1.65, I changed severity for "unusedVariable" from style to warning, but it still show severity "style" in output report

Comment: Cppcheck will always output the "unusedVariable" as "style" in the output report. You have to edit the output report.. for instance using a script or xslt or something.

Comment: you are right that you can't use --rule-file for this.

Comment: So, there's no way to modify the ruleset and change rule severity, the only thing I can do is modify output report